# cocoa-touch: How to pass on a touch to another object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

This is a beginner's question I'm afraid:

I have an UIText which covers the entire screen. I have another transparent view on top of this UITextView so as to be able to recognise swiping gestures (horizontally and vertically), like so:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // UITextView
    CGRect aFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    aTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
    aTextView.text = @"Some sample text.";
    [self.view addSubview:aTextView];

    // canTouchMe
    CGRect canTouchMeFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 
    canTouchMe = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:canTouchMeFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:canTouchMe];
    }
```

Let's consider the user touches (not swipes) the canTouchMe View. In this case, I would like the canTouchMe view to disappear and pass on the touch to the UITextView hiding beneath so that it enters the editing mode and enable the 'natural' scrolling options an UITextView has (i.e. only horizontally).

My touches began method looks like this:

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

How do I tell this method that IF it recognises only **ONE touch**, that it should hide the canTouchMeFrame and **PASS ON the touch** to the UITextView?

Sorry if this is basic, but I have no idea how to implement this. Thanks for any suggestions.

---

EDIT:

I introduced a touchEnded method, but I still have no luck. The touch will not be forwarded to the UITextView. I need to tap twice in order to edit it:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x); // will always be positive
CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y); // will always be positive


if (deltaY == 0 && deltaX == 0) {

    label.text = @"Touch"; [self performSelector:@selector(eraseText) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

    [aTextView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:aTextView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:doneEdit];


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSSet` has a `-count` method.  If `touches` only has one object, then you're responding to a single touch.

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if ([touches count] == 1) {
       [self  hideMyRectangle];
       [someOtherObject touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
       //etc, etc.
       return;
       }
    // if you get here, there's more than one touch.       
    UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This works alright -- the only problem is that my program can now ONLY DETECT touches and not SWIPES any more. I updated the code accordingly (see above). It appears that if I get more than one touch, it doesn't recognise it as such, but only as one touch. E.g. if I swipe, it only recognises it as one touch.